# TextArea semelhante a um Editor de texto ex: VS Code

Tags: react

Gostaria de saber se tem mais lib para react que deixa um textarea igual ao VS Code por exemplo? lib mais proxima disso que achei foi o CodeMirror, gostaria de mais auternativas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se é o que entendi, tem o [ACE Editor](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=howto&api=editor).
A sua implementação é fácil fácil, neste link aqui: [1](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=howto&api=editor), você pode verificar o seu manual, que é tudo muito simples.

Além disso, você pode usar vários temas diferentes e sintaxes de linguagens diferentes também.

**Abaixo, um exemplo mínimo completo.** Se não for isso, removerei a resposta.

```js
var editor = ace.edit("editor");

document.getElementById('editor').style.fontSize = '16px';

editor.setTheme("ace/theme/dracula");

editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");

editor.session.setTabSize(4);

editor.setOptions({
  autoScrollEditorIntoView: true,
  copyWithEmptySelection: true,
});

setTimeout(() => {
  var beautify = ace.require("ace/ext/beautify"); // get reference to extension
  beautify.beautify(editor.session);
}, 500);

//beautify.beautify(editor.session);
document.getElementById("formatar").onclick = function() {
  var beautify = ace.require("ace/ext/beautify"); // get reference to extension
  beautify.beautify(editor.session);
}
```

```css
#editor {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.6/ace.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.6/ext-beautify.js"></script>

<div id="editor">
  function foo(items) { var x = "All this is syntax highlighted"; return x; }
</div>
<a href="../">Voltar</a>
<button id="formatar">Formatar</button>
```